# Empty screen rendering takes 16% CPU on average

Tags: android, libgdx, live-wallpaper

I'm running libGDX app as a live wallpaper. I'm using SpriteBatch and 2D Stage. Cost of rendering an empty (black) screen averages at 16% on Samsung S4 (measured with adb shell top). Seems a little bit much even considering the size of the screen. Is something wrong with my approach?

```
public class TestWallpaper implements ApplicationListener, AndroidWallpaperListener {

    ...

    @Override
    public void render () {
        if (loading && scene.loadUpdate()) {
            doneLoading();
        }

        float timeDelta = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        if(!loading) {
            stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
            stage.draw();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If it is possible in your library - try to limit FPS, this should trim down the CPU usage.

Comment: I've tried but only way to do that on libGDX is to turn the continuous rendering off and request frame render as a timed event. ..and it looks bad :(

Comment: Is it specifically attributing 16% CPU to your package? Because the launcher uses some too. I've found that running the exact same ApplicationListener as a live wallpaper and in a full-screen activity results in a significant framerate drop, but that is because of GPU bottleneck, not CPU.

Comment: Yes. It's my package only.

Comment: You could just add a sleep in your render method to bring the frame rate down.

Comment: Can you compare to a 3rd party wallpaper that doesn't use LibGDX?